# How To Disable Tick Control in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have list in SharePoint Online with Classic View.
The following is the column on my list:
[image]

The following will appear when the form is run:

[image]

My condition:
When the Actual Completion Date is not filled, the Completed field does not appear / disable. but if the Actual Completion Date is filled in, Completed appears and can be filled.

this condition is done when edit item.

How is the code?
Because I'm still newbie in java script.

Thanks the master java script

Answer (score 0):

Test code for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[title='Completed']").hide();
        $("input[title='date']").get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = DatePickerChanged;
        function DatePickerChanged(e) {
            console.log("DatePickerChanged" + $("input[title='date']").val())
            if($("input[title='date']").val()!=""){
                $("input[title='Completed']").show()
            }else{
                $("input[title='Completed']").hide();
            }
        }
        $("input[title='date']").change(function () {
            console.log("input change " + $("input[title='date']").val());
            if($("input[title='date']").val()!=""){
                $("input[title='Completed']").show()
            }else{
                $("input[title='Completed']").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Test result:
[image]
Tip:jQuery selector needs to be adjusted according to your column.
[image]

[jQuery selector document](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)